# Nesting, sort-of: Multiple observations mapping to a single DV measure?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, model-selection, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

This is a made up example, but it gets to a point I am trying to figure out.

I know that you can use a nested model if your IVs are collected in clusters -- for example, if you want to model the effect of "the # of hours a student spends working" on his "grades", you can cluster by school and maybe teacher.

But, what if you want to test the effect of "the # of hours students spend working" on "the ranking of the school"?  Then, you have all observations within a school mapping to a single DV measure.

This seems pretty different.  How should it be modeled?

Comment: Is this correct: your unit of observation is 'student' and for every student you measure which school he belongs to as well as how many hours he spends working? If yes this seems to me like a simple linear model in which you predict the ranking of schools by the hours students spend working.

Comment: Yes.  And the DV is the ranking of the school. (note -- this is actually not at all my topic and completely made up, it's just easier to explain and has the same structure.. so please don't critique the theory, it's meaningless)

Comment: But wouldn't the fact that there is only one DV measurement used for clusters of students artificially reduce the standard error?